# Change data table values based on selected value from dropdown (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, dropdown

so I have a datatable displaying all courses from the database and I want to sort the data using values from dropdown (which contains department of courses) I want to sort all courses depending on the selected department. For example, I selected ICT department, all courses from that department will be displayed on the data table. How will I do this?

Model:

```
 public function getCoursesByDepartment($DepartmentID)
    {
        $this->dbi->select('course.CourseCode, course.CourseTitle');
        $this->dbi->from('course');
        $this->dbi->where('course.DepartmentID', $DepartmentID);
        $res = $this->dbi->get()->result();

        return $res;
    }



public function get_departments() { 
        $result = $this->dbi->select('DepartmentID, DepartmentName')->get('department')->result_array(); 

        $DepartmentID = array(); 
        foreach($result as $r) { 
            $DepartmentID[$r['DepartmentID']] = $r['DepartmentName']; 
        } 

        $DepartmentID[''] = 'Select Department...'; 
        return $DepartmentID; 
    }
```

Controller:

```
 public function getcoursesbydepartment()
 {

        $this->load->model('Admin_model');
        $allcourses = $this->Admin_model->getCoursesByDepartment($DepartmentID);
        $data['courses'] = $allcourses;
        $this->load->view('Admin/managecourses_view', $data);


     }

 public function getcourses() 
{ 
    $data['DepartmentID'] = $this->Admin_model->get_departments(); 
    $this->load->view('Admin/addcourse_view', $data); 
}
```

In my view, my dropdown are populated with values from the database.
View:

```
  <div class="card-pf-body" style="margin-top: 5px;">

      <form class="needs-validation" novalidate >


   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom03"  style="margin-top: 15px!important;margin-left: -20px!important">Sort by department:</label>

        <div class="panel-body" style="margin-left: -36px;margin-top: -15px;"> 
                <!--dropdown input--> 

       <!--HERE IS MY DROPDOWN (VALUES RETRIEVED FROM DATABASE)-->

        <?php echo form_dropdown('DepartmentID', $DepartmentID, '', 'class="form-control"', 'name="DepartmentID"', '#', 'id=departmentid', (isset($_POST['DepartmentID']) ? $_POST['DepartmentID'] : ''), 'id="DepartmentID"') ?>



            </div> 
    </div>    

     <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">

    </div>    
  </div>


   <p style="margin-top: 20px;margin-right: 1000px;margin-left: 5px;width: 80px;margin-bottom: 10px"><font style="color: #ffffff">p</font></p>

</form>

    <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-striped" id="example"> 
      <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Course</th>
      <th>Title</th>
     <!--  <th>Description</th> -->

      <th>Option</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php 
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($courses AS $course): ?>
    <tr>

      <td><?php echo $course->CourseCode; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $course->CourseTitle; ?></td>

    <!--   <td><a href="<?php echo $course->CourseDescription; ?>">View Description</a></td> -->
      <!-- <td><?php echo $course->CourseDescription; ?></td> -->
      <td>
        <a href="#"" onClick="editcourse(<?php echo $course->CourseID;?>)">Edit<i class="fa fa-pencil" style="margin-left: 5px"></i></a>  

       <!--  <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="editcourse(<?php echo $course->CourseID;?>)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button> -->

        &nbsp; |    &nbsp;
       <a href="#" onClick="deletecourse(<?php echo $course->CourseID;?>)"><font style="color: #D2553D;">Delete</font><i class="fa fa-times" style="margin-left: 5px;color: #D2553D;"></i></a>

      </td>
    </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?> 
    </table>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>



<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // matchHeight the contents of each .card-pf and then the .card-pf itself
    $(".row-cards-pf > [class*='col'] > .card-pf .card-pf-title").matchHeight();
    $(".row-cards-pf > [class*='col'] > .card-pf > .card-pf-body").matchHeight();
    $(".row-cards-pf > [class*='col'] > .card-pf > .card-pf-footer").matchHeight();
    $(".row-cards-pf > [class*='col'] > .card-pf").matchHeight();

    // Initialize the vertical navigation
    $().setupVerticalNavigation(true);
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
 </script>
```

Comment: In your controller, where is `$DepartmentID` defined? I just see it referenced.

Comment: I edited the code :) can you check it

Comment: i've updated my answer to reflect the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to render the page with all options and then, on select change, redirect the user to the same page with an additional url attribute `/somepage/{someid}`

```
// [CONTROLLER]
// specific department: /getcoursesbydepartment/{dept_id}
// all departments:     /getcoursesbydepartment/
public function getcoursesbydepartment($DepartmentID = null) {
    $this->load->model('Admin_model');
    $data['departments'] = $this->Admin_model->get_departments();
    $data['courses'] = $this->Admin_model->getCoursesByDepartment($DepartmentID);
    $data['selected_department'] = $DepartmentID; // added
    $this->load->view('Admin/managecourses_view', $data);
}
```

This necessitates a change in your model code:

*Note: I've added so the function returns null if there are no results, this is generally a good practice (to either return null, false or an empty `array()`). Otherwise, `result()` and `foreach` in view will fail if there are no rows.*

```
public function getCoursesByDepartment($DepartmentID = null) {
    $this->dbi->select('course.CourseCode, course.CourseTitle');
    $this->dbi->from('course');
    if (!is_null($DepartmentID)) {
        $this->dbi->where('course.DepartmentID', $DepartmentID);
    }
    $query = $this->dbi->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() < 1) {
        return null;
    }
    return $query->result();
}
```

Your dropdown code also looked a bit off, I fixed it and added the selected department as the value to be selected. As you will note, if nothing is selected the value will be `null` according to the controller code.

```
//https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#form_dropdown
//form_dropdown([$name = ''[, $options = array()[, $selected = array()[, $extra = '']]]])
echo form_dropdown('DepartmentID', $departments, $selected_department, 'class="form-control" id="DepartmentID"');
```

The `$DepartmentID` variable should be an array that looks like:

`array('93'=>'HR', '21'=>'Marketing')` where the numbers are the department id's (UPDATE: it looks like you are doing that right).

Now all you have to do is, using js or jquery, on select change redirect to:
`/getcoursesbydepartment/{dept_id}` where `{dept_id}` is the value of the select box.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: selected_department

Filename: Admin/managecourses_view.php

Line Number: 1244

Comment: why is selected_department not recognized by the view?

Comment: does your controller look *exactly* like mine? e.g. `$data['selected_department'] = $DepartmentID;` and `public function getcoursesbydepartment($DepartmentID = null)`?

Comment: What should be the value of the department id here?
 $data['selected_department'] = $DepartmentID;

Comment: `$DepartmentID` comes from the url see: `getcoursesbydepartment($DepartmentID = null)` usage: `/getcoursesbydepartment/{dept_id}` ... When `/getcoursesbydepartment/123`, department id is 123

Comment: Further, my answer was made before you made mods to your question. I didn't know you had 2 controllers, you can simplify to 1 by renaming my controller above to just `getcourses` and access the specific depts via `getcourses/{dept_id}`

Comment: I get that part sir but I have an error on this part, it says that the $selected_department is an undefined variable: <?php echo form_dropdown('DepartmentID', $DepartmentID, $selected_department, 'class="form-control" id="DepartmentID"'); ?>

Comment: Can you print screen your code (not browser error), and post on imgur and put url here?

Comment: Also is the view code you posted: `Admin/managecourses_view`? That has both the dropdown and the courses?

Comment: Yes sir it has both the dropdown and all the courses

Comment: Ok and in your browser you are going to `getcoursesbydepartment` (and seeing error here) not `viewcourses`?

Comment: Well as you see `$data['selected_department']` is only defined in "my" controller function  `getcoursesbydepartment` thus the error ;) ..

Comment: I have no errors now thank you!!  I just have to do a js function to call the selected value from the dropdown right?

Comment: Yes you just need to get the value and redirect to `/getcoursesbydepartment/{select_value}`